# Load very large pickle file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deserialization, pickle

so for my bachelors thesis I am supposed to train a classifier on a very large dataset. I'm gonna get access to my Uni's deep learning cluster at some point, but for now I was told to do a bit of data exploration on the data on my own device. I was told to only use 10% of the data. Thing is the pickle file is absolutely massive (8.3 GB on my 16 GB system) and when I try to load it straight up, the system crashes.

I have an excel which contains sample data, so I figured I could pickle the sample data and write a script which only reads the first 10% or sth of the file. However when I pickled it and looked at it using pickletools.dis() I realized, that I can't just read the top 10% of the file, since it essentially doesnt go row by row, but column by column. So if I were to take the first 10%, I would have data which is entirely useless. I am not sure if this is the case for every pickle file, cause in some thread I have seen one that goes row by row, but I can't check what is the case for my main file, cause I can't inspect it at all.

How could I approach this issue (besides buying more RAM lol)?

Comment: I'd ask your prof to use a stronger machine to split it for you.

Comment: I mean, at some point I will need access to a stronger machine for training purposes anyhow, so if there is no way around it, I might just have to do it now.

Comment: I'm not saying that you need to work fully on the stronger machine right now. What I'm suggesting is that you use the stronger hardware temporarily to load the large dataset and split it, such that you can take the smaller input and work offline on your local machine.

Comment: I'll ask him about it. Quick question for my understanding. Do pickle-files always go column by column or is there a chance, that they go row by row?

Comment: Use HDF5 instead of Pickle, it is much more memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sample your file I would recommend you working with the entire file using cloud competing.

You can create a free account in AWS or AZURE using those links

https://aws.amazon.com/pt/free 
https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/free/

I would suggest you use AZURE because you will receive 200 dollars and will have more flexibility to use as you want.

After create you account you can create a powerful virtual machine with enough memory to read your entire file.

You can check the link bellow to see how to use Azure azure-machine-learning to create your VM:

https://github.com/maxreis86/FIEP-Machine-Learning-e-Computacao-em-Nuvem#azure-machine-learning

Comment: European data protection laws are very strict, I am not sure if I am legally allowed to upload the file anywhere, even if it is a private VM. I will have to consult my professor for this.

Comment: I personally that the security inside a virtual machine is the same of your local machine.  Any one would need a username and password to login the same way you need to login in your local computer.

Comment: that might very well be true, but that does not mean I am allowed to do it. :)

Comment: @christallclear That's probably another thing you really should clear up with your prof, ASAP. Frankly, if it was anything even remotely sensitive, I'd be surprised that they'd give the whole dataset to an undergrad student to play with on their own machine.

Comment: @DanMašek the data is completely anonymized and pseudomized. realistically nothing in there could be used to indentify any party involved, not the companies or the customers. yet that does not mean that I am allowed to put it on some VM, especially not amazon or microsoft given the way in which they treat data privacy. law is law, doesnt matter if it makes sense or not.

Comment: @christallclear Ummm... :) Notice I never said "upload it wherever you want without worry". On the contrary, I suggested that you'd better damn make sure you know exactly what you may or may not do and what are the consequences. I only remarked the unlikelyhood of you being given something sensitive without being properly informed -- that would be rather negligent from the school's side. (Some of us here do this sort of stuff for a living, you know?)

Comment: @DanMašek No need to get hostile sir. :) Some of us are also americans where data protection is a completely foreign concept. I did not get permission from my prof or the company associated with my thesis to put the data anywhere but my own machine or the deep learning cluster of my university at some point, so I am not gonna stick it on some cloud computing service, especiallly not if I am gonna pay for it. Also negligence describes the experience of my thesis so far very well, so who knows... The data in itself is absolutely harmless, but that doesnt mean I wont get fined if I "misplace" it.